# How to make output from web scraping python selenium in div class to output text

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

This is my Code `

```
from attr import attr
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

datas = []
key = 'sepatu'
jenis = 'teplek'
url = 'https://website.com/search/?term={}+{}'.format(key,jenis)
headers = {
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0'
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup (req.text, 'html.parser')
sepatu = soup.find_all('div', 'element_1')
for it in sepatu:
    harga = it.find('div','element').__str__
    datas.append([harga])
hasil = ['Harga'] 
write = csv.writer(open('result/{}_{}.csv'.format(key,jenis), 'w', newline=''))
write.writerow (hasil)
for d in datas: write.writerow(d)
```

this is Output from this code

| Column A |
| --- |
| <bound method Tag.**unicode** of Rp 88.000 |

>


<bound method Tag.**unicode** of  Rp 200.000 >

how to turn that output to this output

| Column A |
| --- |
| Rp 88.000 |
| Rp 200.000 |

i was try
`harga = it.find('div','element').__str__` to `harga = it.find('div','element').text` but i got error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

i try to learn web scraping python selenium but i got block by output into text and i expecting i want  all the output into text

Comment: try: `harga.get_attribute('textContent')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **.text** in this line

```
harga = soup.find("div", {"class": "db gM ei b hE be f16-360-o ff vb uT ellipsis-1"}).text
```

Then you will get an output like this

| Nama Sepatu | Harga |
| --- | --- |
| Sepatu A | Rp.24.000 |

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with the commands you use to locate the elements. If element is not found, BS returns None for them.
What mean `element_1` and `element` in this lines?:

```
sepatu = soup.find_all('div', 'element_1')
```

and

```
harga = it.find('div','element').__str__
```

If these are IDs, you need to set it this way:

```
sepatu = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'element_1'})
```

If it's a class name:

```
sepatu = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'element_1'})
```

Or any other attribute:

```
sepatu = soup.find_all('div', {'attr_name': 'element_1'})
```

When an element is found you can use `.text` property to get its text